# Remove millisecond part of created_at in SQL to compare with other datetime

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find duplicates on my datetime. Since my `created_at` is not equal with any rows because of the milliseconds, I want to remove it so I can now display all the duplicates with the same `created_at`. But this syntax returns an error that `datetime column does not exist in my CONVERT`

```
SELECT
sd.global_code AS sd_id,
sm.tag AS tag,
SUM(sm.quantity) AS quantity,
CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, sm.created_at, 120), 120) AS date ## returns an error ##
FROM stock_distributions sd
INNER JOIN stock_movements sm ON sd.id = sm.stock_distribution_id
WHERE (sm.tag = 'Shelf Transfer' OR sm.tag = 'Transfer (Put-Away to Shelf)')
AND sl.site_id = 4
GROUP BY sd.global_code
HAVING SUM(sm.quantity) < 0
AND COUNT(convert(datetime, convert(varchar, sm.created_at, 120), 120)) > 1
```

am I doing the right thing? Is there a faster way on SELECTING `sm.created_at` with the same date and time until the seconds only so the output would be something like `2019-03-31 4:08:33`?

Comment: Tis certainly does not look like Postgres code.  What database are you really using?  Your code will not work for multiple reasons in any database.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I think it's just plain `sql` I am running this command in rails. I will remove the tag.

Comment: @eibersji There is no such thing as plain SQL. Please tag with the database that you are using.

Comment: `convert()` is not part of standard ("plain") SQL

Comment: ## is not how comments are done isn sql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I have figured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use string comparisons by converting the dates to strings

```
to_char( mydate, 'rrrrmmddhh24ss' )
```

Comment: thank you for this! though i did mine like `TO_CHAR( sm.created_at AT TIME ZONE 'GMT+8', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' ) AS date` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  And it needs a lot of fixing.  The `SELECT` is inconsistent with the `GROUP BY` keys, for instance.

If you want to find global codes at the same time, but ignoring milliseconds, I would recommend `datetimefromparts()`:

```
SELECT sd.global_code AS sd_id,
       datetimefromparts(year(sm.created_at), month(sm.created_at), day(sm.created_at),
                         datepart(hour, sm.created_at), datepart(minute, sm.created_at), datepart(second, sm.created_at),
                         0
                        ) as dt
       SUM(sm.quantity) AS quantity
FROM stock_distributions sd INNER JOIN
     stock_movements sm
     ON sd.id = sm.stock_distribution_id
WHERE sm.tag IN ('Shelf Transfer', sm.tag = 'Transfer (Put-Away to Shelf)') AND
      sl.site_id = 4
GROUP BY sd.global_code, 
         datetimefromparts(year(sm.created_at), month(sm.created_at), day(sm.created_at),
                         datepart(hour, sm.created_at), datepart(minute, sm.created_at), datepart(second, sm.created_at),
                         0
                        )
HAVING SUM(sm.quantity) < 0 AND COUNT(*) > 1;
```

In Postgres, this is much simpler:

```
SELECT sd.global_code AS sd_id,
       date_trunc('second', sm.created_at) as dt,            SUM(sm.quantity) AS quantity
FROM stock_distributions sd INNER JOIN
     stock_movements sm
     ON sd.id = sm.stock_distribution_id
WHERE sm.tag IN ('Shelf Transfer', sm.tag = 'Transfer (Put-Away to Shelf)') AND
      sl.site_id = 4
GROUP BY sd.global_code, dt
HAVING SUM(sm.quantity) < 0 AND COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I never thought about datetimeforparts however it gives me the error: ` PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function year(timestamp without time zone) does not exist`

Comment: @eibersji . . . You really need to understand what database you are using.  In Postgres, this is much simpler; you can use `date_trunc()`.